# How to make a bean discoverable by Quarkus CDI without using annotations

Tags: quarkus

I have a simple Quarkus resource:

```
  @Path("/rosters")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public class RosterResource {

    private final RosterService rosterService;
    public RosterResource(RosterService rosterService){
        this.rosterService = rosterService;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{rosterId}")
    public Response getRoster(@PathParam("rosterId")Long rosterId){
        return Response.ok(rosterService.getRosterById(rosterId)).build();
    }

}
```

I am trying to inject the `RosterService`instance in my resource, but I am getting a `javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException`. However,  if I use the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation on `RosterService`, then everything works just fine. Is there a way of injecting the `RosterService` class in my resource without using annotations? In other words, is there a way of making `RosterService` discoverable by the Quarkus container without directly annotating the class?

*Edit*: looking into the [CDI docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-integration), it seems that you can manually register beans using a method with a `@BuildStep` annotation. However, it is not clear to me which class should contain the annotated method)

Another option would be to use a [Jandex index](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#bean_discovery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Quarkus only implements so called *annotated* bean discovery. That means that all CDI beans in Quarkus have to have a *bean defining annotation*. `@ApplicationScoped` is one of them.

EDIT: regarding a Jandex index, that allows you to scan for beans in additional JARs. In other words, it will only expand the set of classes that are scanned for a bean defining annotation.

When it comes to a `@BuildStep` method -- that is only possible in a Quarkus extension. Extensions are powerful (and indeed they can define additional beans) but also complex. You can start at https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension, but it may feel overwhelming. It may also feel like this is not the right thing to do if you want to just make your class a bean -- and that would be true. But if your class comes from an external library that you can't change, extension makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you don't want to annotate your service class with `@ApplicationScoped` (or any other of the bean discover/scope annotations)?

The only other way that I'm aware of (instead of annotations) is - as you yourself mentioned - the use of [Jandex index](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#how-to-generate-a-jandex-index).

Comment: Hello Mathias, the reason is a bit pedantic related to keeping the domain model clean with no annotations.